# How do I populate my data extension when a new lead or contact is created in Salesforce?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I would like to use Journey Builder to automatically send out welcome emails to any new contact or lead that is created in salesforce.  I have different emails depending on the lead source.

Comment: Hello Aggie , Please can you clear your business requirements.For sending welcome email you can write a trigger according to what you want to perform.
Thanks,
Pritam Shekhawat

Comment: Pritam,  are you aware the question is about exacttarget/marketing-cloud ?

Answer (score 0):

**In below two ways you can achieve this.**

1. Create a report in SalesForce. And then in Marketing Cloud, have a Salesforce Data Extension by creating an Import Definition (using the same SF report.)
2. Create a Salesforce Synchronized data extension in contact builder.

Answer (score 0):

With journey builder (as provided in the question) you simply use a Salesforce Entry Event to define the object which acts as trigger (needs to be lead, contact, person account or any other object with a lookup to one of those), the event (create, update or both) and the filter criteria if necessary.

To target your specific email versions to the people with the correct field values start off with a decision split based on those criteria. On each resulting path you can then put the email that matches the criteria defined before.